# Excel Conditional Formatting of Values in Column B while grouped on Column A

Tags: excel, grouping, conditional-formatting, excel-2016

I have looked all over for some existing idea of how to accomplish this but I'm not having any luck. I have data like below. I need to color code the values in Column B in groups based on Column A.

```
Item | Date     | Desired Color  
A1   | 20210510 | Red  
A1   | 20211220 | Green  
A3   | 20200915 | Green  
A4   | 20220418 | Green  
B5   | 20210617 | Red  
B5   | 20221110 | Green  
B5   | 20221110 | Green  
B7   | 20200220 | Red  
B7   | 20210415 | Orange  
B7   | 20210710 | Yellow  
B7   | 20220131 | Green
```

The data always comes into the sheet sorted by item first then the date. The oldest date for each item should be red and the newest green with any other dates graduating from green to yellow to orange and red. I know how to group rows together to make them the same color by item and I know how to do graduated coloring by value. Just can't figure out how to combine the two.

Comment: and what color are singleton groups like A3? jk. Not possible with just the basic conditional formatting tool: it takes ranges as input. You want a _Graded 3-Color Scale_ but for each group of rows. That is one formating __rule__ per group. You do not want to do that manually, and no formula can generate them. Either macros, or another trick: create a hidden 3rd column with a formula that outputs a v-value ranging 1-0 per group-row, using a VLOOKUP, and then use a single formatting rule for all rows, based on that column.

Comment: I thought about trying to come up with a third column to assign a number value to each row. I just can't get my head around the logic to do it. I had a formula that gave a running count per group but that wouldn't account for the fact that there may be more than one row in a group with the same date. Like B5 for example. My formula returns a count of 1, 2, 3 when I would need it to be 1, 2, 2 to make the formatting idea I had work. Your idea of doing a 0-1 calculation though just might do the trick if I can figure out  a formula that will use the oldest date as 0 and the newest as 1.

Comment: Then use the difference between the two as well as the others in between to get my fractions. Thanks for the help. Let me see what I can come up with.